# Does $\lim_{\epsilon\to0^+}\int_0^\pi e^{\epsilon i e^{i \theta }}d\theta=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^\pi e^{\frac{i e^{i \theta}}{n}}d\theta$?

Tags: calculus

I'd like to have
$$\lim_{\epsilon\to0^+}\int_0^\pi e^{\epsilon i e^{i \theta }}d\theta=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^\pi e^{\frac{i e^{i \theta}}{n}}d\theta$$
in order to have $f_n(\theta)$ uniformly converge to 1 (and subsequently move the limit inside the integral).

I'm under the impression that the limit must go to infinity in order to apply the definition of uniform convergence, so am I allowed to change the limit like so?

Please feel free to point out any errors I might've made!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dominated convergenec Theorem is applicable to both sides since $|e^{ia}|=1$ for any real number $a$. Hence both ides of the equation are equal to $\pi$.

Comment: Thanks for answering! Can you explain how DCT can be applied to the left hand side? I thought you needed the limit on the outside to go to infinity in order to use it.

Comment: Showing that the limit on the left side is $\pi$ is equivalent to showing that the limit as $n \to \infty$ of $\int_0^{\pi} e^{\epsilon_n e^{i\theta}} d\theta =\pi$ for any sequence $(\epsilon_n) \to 0$. @JohnSmith

Comment: Okay, thanks for the clarification!